# Replace NaN value with a median of all rows but select only some rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is a follow up on my earlier [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64859946/replace-nan-value-with-a-median) but I know need to add a selection of particular rows to apply the changed values to.

```
np.random.seed(0)
rng = pd.date_range('2020-09-24', periods=20, freq='0.2H')
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Date': rng, 'Val': np.random.randn(len(rng)), 'Dist' :np.random.randn(len(rng)), 'Variant' : ["Red", "Blue", "Blue", "Yellow","Blue", "Blue", "Yellow", "Blue", "Yellow","Blue", "Red", "Red", "Red", "Red","Blue", "Blue",  "Yellow","Red",  "Yellow", "Yellow"]}) 
df.Dist[df.Dist<=-0.6] = np.nan
df.Val[df.Val<=-0.5] = np.nan
```

Produce this data:
[image]

I was provided with this great solution:

```
cols = ['Val','Dist']
df[cols] =  df[cols].fillna(df.groupby(df.Date.dt.floor('H'))
                              [cols].transform('median')
                           )
```

But now I do not know how to make it so that the median for each hour is calculated across all the values in the column but only used to fill the ones with Red in the variant column?
Again that is median across the whole of each Dist and Val column independently.
This would work such that NaN values would be left in Yellow and Blue rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the indexes from the Red Variants, then calculate the median using the Variant column as well in `groupby`, then update only your target indexes.

```
cols = ['Val','Dist']
idx_red = df.Variant.eq('Red')
df.loc[idx_red, cols] = df.loc[idx_red, cols].fillna(df.groupby([df.Date.dt.floor('H')])[cols].transform('median')[idx_red])
```

Output:

```
                  Date       Val      Dist Variant
0  2020-09-24 00:00:00  1.764052       NaN     Red
1  2020-09-24 00:12:00  0.400157  0.653619    Blue
2  2020-09-24 00:24:00  0.978738  0.864436    Blue
3  2020-09-24 00:36:00  2.240893       NaN  Yellow
4  2020-09-24 00:48:00  1.867558  2.269755    Blue
5  2020-09-24 01:00:00       NaN       NaN    Blue
6  2020-09-24 01:12:00  0.950088  0.045759  Yellow
7  2020-09-24 01:24:00 -0.151357 -0.187184    Blue
8  2020-09-24 01:36:00 -0.103219  1.532779  Yellow
9  2020-09-24 01:48:00  0.410599  1.469359    Blue
10 2020-09-24 02:00:00  0.144044  0.154947     Red
11 2020-09-24 02:12:00  1.454274  0.378163     Red
12 2020-09-24 02:24:00  0.761038  0.266555     Red
13 2020-09-24 02:36:00  0.121675  0.266555     Red
14 2020-09-24 02:48:00  0.443863 -0.347912    Blue
15 2020-09-24 03:00:00  0.333674  0.156349    Blue
16 2020-09-24 03:12:00  1.494079  1.230291  Yellow
17 2020-09-24 03:24:00 -0.205158  1.202380     Red
18 2020-09-24 03:36:00  0.313068 -0.387327  Yellow
19 2020-09-24 03:48:00       NaN -0.302303  Yellow
```

Note: See that other Variant but "Red" is not updated, and the red ones with only NAs is not updated as well.

Comment: This is great thanks, particularly the `.eq`  which I wasn't aware of.